# Flash side scrolling game theory

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

AS3.0 newbie here.

My goal: To create a side-scrolling motocross game (horizontal - already have terms on side scrolling methodology).

1. The bike - should react to jumps, etc.

   - Wheels need to turn when gas is pressed, etc (is this a basic animation on keyboard events, or is it actually what 'drives' the machine??)
2. The rider - should hang on to bike, lean forward, backward, etc.

My question lies within where should be the best place to start? I know this isn't going to happen over night, and my primary focus is on the bike & suspension & rider physics (making sure the suspension/bike/rider react correctly to bumps).

The end result (someday) will be something similar to:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpR0wbE_6Qs

Kind of an abstract question, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: off topic: you will get better answers at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agreed, this question should be moved to gamedev

Comment: I suggest to read [gamedev faq](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting this question becuase it says you **should NOT ask** questions like this **how to make (or start making) a particular type of game**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of resources for Flash game development out there,

- http://www.seinia.com/ teaches some useful basics.
- Adobe has a good list of some engines as well: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/gaming_engines.html

I would definitely check out [Box2D](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/) and [Fixel](http://flixel.org/features.html) as they are pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar topic with a few good suggestions for side scrolling physics games: [Scrolling the 2d world with physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028298/scrolling-the-2d-world-with-physics)